# Cast from hexadecimal to unsigned int* in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I have an assignment that were supposed to evaluate some pointer manipulation expressions and memory leak situations in C/C++. There's one I'm stuck with:

`unsigned int* pInt = (unsigned int*) 0x403004;`

Right off the bat this is suspicious to me, but in the assignment this line is theoretically working, however running the program I'm get segfault right at this line.

The question is: Is this right or even is possible or the professor is just fooling us telling this is right? I've seen some examples and questions with string "hex" to int, but nothing regarding "pure hex" to int or int*

Comment: If your program has not been allocated memory at address 0x403004 and you try to use it for anything, a segfault is one of the better outcomes.

Comment: the problem is not in the cast.  The problem is in what you do with that pointer afterwards.  In 90% of the cases a pointer created like this is bogus, and any attempt to do anything with it is bound to produce a segfault.  So, you might want to tell us more about the assignment.

Comment: Here's a quick experiment. Make a program like this: `int main() { unsigned int* pInt = (unsigned int*) 0x403004; }` All it does is assign the pointer and should be valid even if the address is 100% BS because it's not being accessed.

Comment: Examine the contents of memory at the address at runtime, chances are it points to random area, and the operating system saw that the code was accessing memory that it should not have accessed and killed it with a segfault.

Comment: Makes sense, theres no way to tell, at the given program, to know if `0x403004` is allocated for me. Is fair to say if it's running in Windows it would cause blu scren? (I'm using linux)

Comment: it's likely to get inside a room illegally which doesn't belong to you. also in arrays where writing to memory that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: Under DOS, back in the old days, if the address was legitimate and valid, you could actually do something, for example, `unsigned int* pInt = (unsigned int*) 0xB800;` you could write int (was a 16bit) value to the video memory. That is where undefined behaviour actually turned out to be legitimate. :P Nowadays, good luck with writing code, unless its embedded platform where the addresses *are* known.

Comment: @t0mm13b seems fun and dangerous

Comment: @user4581301 Your program is  undefined behaviour if no object exists at that address

Comment: @M.M so that makes the cast itself verboten? Didn't expect that, but it makes sense when you stop to think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int* pInt = (unsigned int*) 0x403004;
```

Two things are suspicious here:

- Unless, you are writing some specialized Software like device drivers or OS, or you are in some embedded or special system where memory is fixed, seeing memory address hardcoded is certainly suspicious. Your program will (at best) fail if it tries to access memory it doesn't have the access rights to.
- On the right hand side, the compiler first deduces the value `0x403004` as in `int` and will correctly convert it to a pointer. Thus, your Segfault is probably as a result of the first point.

Comment: @user4581301. There wasn't, but I only put that up to explain the dangers upfront of doing something like `unsigned int* pInt = (unsigned int*) myInt;`. Nonetheless, answer tweaked.

Answer (score 3):

*unsigned int* pInt = (unsigned int*) 0x403004;*

Possible?:  yes (compiles, builds just fine)

Is it right?:  depends on what for. Evidently it is useful for illustration in a classroom assignment.

Is it recommended? no.  It will invoke *[undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)*.  You are creating a variable that points to a location in memory that you may or may not have rights to. If you never use it, fine.  But if you do use it, the results are indeterminate.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to perform the cast if no object exists at the location

Answer (score 2):

it works fine only if that number represents an already allocated memory
eg:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 7;
    std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl; // 7
    std::cout << "&i: " << &i << std::endl; // in my case: 0018FF44
    unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)0x0018FF44; // it's ok

    /*
    this is just for explaining because the address of i may differ at anytime the program
    launches thus 0018FF44 will no longer be assigned to i and consequently segfault.

    the right thing is to make pointer points always to whatever i may take as an address.
    to do so:
    */

    //int* ptr = (unsigned int*)&i; // not i but the address of i     

    (*ptr)++;

    std::cout << i << std::endl; // 8
    // above we changed i through pointer ptr

    int* pRandom = (int*)0xAB2FC0DE0; // this causes me segfault
    *pRandom = 5; // segfault

    std::cout << "*pRandom: " << *pRandom << std::endl; // segfault

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This second part is exactly what I was doing, this example clarifies things

Comment: ok it's like a bet. the right thing we right only to an allocated memory otherwise we are facing a disaster at anytime.

Comment: Yes, I run your code and this adress crashed on my computer. Insted of hard code the adress I put &i

Comment: yes that is it. because at anytime you run program the i is assigned a random unallocated address

Comment: I wish there was a better way to do this example, @Raindrop7 but I can't think of one. Best I can recommend is a big, fat, obvious comment that warns readers that "0x0018FF44 is not portable. You cannot cut and paste this example onto your computer and make it run. For demonstration purposes only!"